# Blazor server app running directly via exe not showing https localhost in cmd window & SQL data access not working. Works fine in VS debugging mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, web-hosting

I have a Blazor server app, which is exported into some files and an exe upon publishing. In this setup, I have 2 machines. Machine A which is being used for development and is hosting the SQL server express instance.

##### Scenario 1:

I run the app on Machine A. I get the following screen.

[image: console1]

Next I open chrome and open either of the 2 localhost links and the intended website loads with the data being queried from SQL server and displayed on webpage.

Everything works as intended.

##### Scenario 2:

With the same setup as above, since the cmd window in indicating an active web server running, I tried to open the website on my phone using the Machine A's IP. It didn't work. This is problem 1. Getting this to work on other machines.

##### Scenario 3:

In this scenario, I tried to run the app on machine B with the SQL server still running on machine A. They are both in the same network. Upon running the exe, I get the following:
[image: console2]

I am now not getting the https option. Which doesn't bother me too much if it worked. When I try to run the app, I get this new line added to cmd window.
[image: console3]

When I try to open the localhost 5000, the website loads but no data is fetched from SQL server. So i guess i am not able to access my SQL server on machine A from machine B due to some authentication issue.

I do not want to use IIS unless there is no other way. this is an internal tool so security and elegance isn't an issue. Ease of use is the most important goal. Running the exe direct is easiest for the end user.

Thanks for any suggestions.